# Error generating Entity class(ssdl, csdl, msl, etc) from EdmGem.exe in mysql db

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to generate Entity class (ssdl, csdl, msl, etc,.) from EdmGen.exe in mysql database through Visual studio command line and I get the exception.

here is my command :

```
EdmGen.exe /mode:FullGeneration /outssdl:"D:\ORM\test.ssdl" /outcsdl:"D:\ORM\test.csdl" /outmsl:"D:\ORM\test.msl" /outviews:"D:\ORM\test.views" /entitycontainer:test /namespace:test /outobjectlayer:" D:\ORM\test.cs" /connectionstring:"data source=10.10.200.10; Port = 3306;User Id=root; password=root;Initial Catalog =test" /provider:MySql.Data.MySqlClient
```

error : 
**error 6003: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the in
ner exception for details.
        Fatal error encountered during command execution.
                Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
                        Reading from the stream has failed.Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
                                        An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host**

The same command is working fine a month before on this server, but now it is not working.

Also note that, through ASP.NET web application I am able connect this mysql database server and able to read and insert the datas.

Can any one please provide me the solution for this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your .edmx is managing to connect you can generate for him.

Open your edmx in Designer mode, go to properties, change the property "Metadata Artifact Processing" of "Embed in Output Assembly" to "Copy to Output Directory". Now save the project, the files are generated.